# R geom_bar and facet_grid labels on top of bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, facet-grid

I am trying to make this graph look better, and I'm stuck with the labels (the numbers in this case). How can I make them to show on the top of their correspondent bar? Notice it is a facet_grid.
I have the following code and the output:

```
ggplot(articles_europaoccidental_sex_count_unique_group, aes(Country, percentage)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", aes(fill=Gender)) + 
    facet_grid(~Propuesta) + geom_text(aes(label = round(percentage, 2)), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), vjust = -1)
```

[image]
Thanks!

Comment: try to add `group=Gender` to `geom_text` `aes`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there, just you need to move `aes(fill=Gender)` to inside `ggplot`

```
library(tidyverse)
#Reproducible data set
test_mtcars <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl,am, gear) %>% summarise(mean = mean(mpg))

ggplot(test_mtcars, aes(as.factor(cyl), mean, fill=as.factor(am))) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + 
facet_grid(~gear) + geom_text(aes(label = round(mean, 2)), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), vjust = -1)
```

[image]